# Parsley Validation Sum of Fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, parsley.js

I am working on an application that has a dynamic form. It doesn't have JS validation and to integrate some validation and as I see Parsley is the way to go. I managed configure all but one feature required...

There is some business logic as follows.

> Total sum of splits should be >= $1

Splits are kind of inserted dynamically. But in the end will look some thing like this.

```
<input id="forms_donation_splits_attributes_1548177744460_dollars" name="forms_donation[splits_attributes][1548177744460][dollars]" size="30" type="text">
<input id="forms_donation_splits_attributes_1894155566460_dollars" name="forms_donation[splits_attributes][1894155566460][dollars]" size="30" type="text">
<input id="forms_donation_splits_attributes_1855668896445_dollars" name="forms_donation[splits_attributes][1855668896445][dollars]" size="30" type="text">
```

What I want to do is to sum these fields and if their total is less than 1 to show an error message.

Is there a way to achieve this?

While not relevant, if it is helpful to other suggestions, this is a Rails application.

Answer (score 1):

Interdependent inputs are a bit tricky.

[This example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html) shows how to validate a group of inputs.